# Socket Stream - Python (Cutting part of the message)

Tags: python, sockets, opencv, numpy

- **What I try to do:** Recording a video and then sending it from one pc to another one, with Socket Stream. For that I use the OpenCV
  library CV2, NumPy and Socket.
- **The problem:** When I send the the frames, it only sends a part of the whole (43776 of 921600), which leaves an error afterwards, when I
  try to display to frame on the other pc.

**The Server:**

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import cv2
import numpy as np

ip = "XXX.XXX.X.XXX"

def Test(Given_List):
    y = 0
    temp = []
    Frame_List = []

    for kappa in range(480):
        Frame_List.append([])

    for each in Given_List:

        if len(temp) < 3:
            temp.append(each)

        if len(temp) >= 3:
            Frame_List[y].append(temp)
            temp = []

        if len(Frame_List[y]) >= 640:
            y += 1
    return Frame_List


while True:
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((ip,50000))
    data = client_socket.recv(10240000)
    s = np.fromstring(data, dtype=np.uint8)
    nice = np.asarray(Test(s))
    cv2.imshow('frame', nice)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

The Client:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import cv2

#Receiver ip
ip = "XXX.XXX.X.XXX"
port = 50000

#Set up socket and stuff 
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind(("XXX.XXX.X.XXX", port))
server.listen(1)

#Define the cam stuff
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    s, add = server.accept()
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    n = frame.tobytes()

    if ret:
        s.sendall(n)
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
s.close()
```

Comment: BTW: if program uses `listen` and `accept` then we call it `"server"`, not` "client"` because it waits for client (and serves data).

Comment: documentation suggests to use `4096` for `recv()` (and receive in loop) because system/socket may use buffer with size `4096`. See: [socket.recv()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv)

Comment: while true : Create more connection why ? server accept only one. Another question is where your buffer size, did you know default buf_size ? Socket is a pipe , dont need another socket for send/recv `multipart` data.

Comment: Socket need bidirectional communication for checkin all frame/data is correct. Maybe you want single way communication, need use server push methods or static_file server.

Comment: I copied the socket part, because whatever I tried with my own code, didn't work out, so I didn't change anything at all.

I have now changed the recv size to 4096 and took the connection part out of the loop, but none of them helped at all.

The only thing that doesn't work is the amount of  data I send, the connection works fine.

Comment: @dsgdfg I have tried to use SOCK_DGRAM for a one way connection, but changed to SOCK_STREAM to send a bigger amount of data, which didn't work, as it seems.

Comment: Sock_DGRAM required two (2) socket_server. Dgram don't use randomly ports(so i tested on my MCU got 10 packets on 0.1702 second(512 byte buffer)).  TCP connection got 50ms delay (tcp_no_delay ignore it) but  every packet required source available check for using randomly port.

Comment: my opinion you missing a socket definition information. Create socket - check health - check buffer - send data - send data confirmation- finished casting - close socket on client side.

Comment: I'm kinda new to socket and all that stuff, that's why I have trouble setting it up correctly. Just used it for a little project, since I'm not very experienced in programming yet, I try to learn it all.

I will look up the things you mentioned and try to correct my code and make it work.
Thanks for the help ^^ @dsgdfg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the amount of data exceeds the maximum amount of the socket, so I changed the video resolution to 320x240 and now it works fine.